# What does it mean when a blue arrow icon is shown on the commit dialog?

Tags: tortoisesvn

The commit dialog shows blue arrow icon overlays on some of the files. What does this mean?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These files are either file externals, or inside an external folder.
Meaning those files and folders are included via the `svn:externals` property.

Comment: In this case, the files weren't included via `svn:externals`. Does that mean the problem is that the folder containing the files hasn't yet been added to source control?